# Centering a SVG path

Tags: html, xml, svg, path

is there a way to center my `<path>` in an `SVG`-File?

This is my SVG:
xml

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 72 72">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#444444" />
    <path d="M5.7 0L1.4 10.985V55.88h15.284V64h8.597l8.12-8.12h12.418l16.716-16.716V0H5.7zm51.104 36.3L47.25 45.85H31.967l-8.12 8.12v-8.12H10.952V5.73h45.85V36.3zM47.25 16.716v16.716h-5.73V16.716h5.73zm-15.284 0v16.716h-5.73V16.716h5.73z" fill="#6441A4" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a suitable transform. This seems fairly close:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 72 72">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#444444" />
    <path fill="#6441A4" 
          transform="translate(3.95 3.95)" 
          d="M5.7 0L1.4 10.985V55.88h15.284V64h8.597l8.12-8.12h12.418l16.716-16.716V0H5.7zm51.104 36.3L47.25 45.85H31.967l-8.12 8.12v-8.12H10.952V5.73h45.85V36.3zM47.25 16.716v16.716h-5.73V16.716h5.73zm-15.284 0v16.716h-5.73V16.716h5.73z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: How do I make the path a bit smaller?

Comment: Learn **all** the ``transform`` settings, maybe ``scale`` is what you need - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#scale

Answer (score 0):

Another quick fix could be setting **negative viewBox x/y values** like so:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-3.95  -3.95  72 72" >
 <rect x="-3.95" y="-3.95" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#444444" />        
 <path fill="#6441A4" 
          d="M5.7 0L1.4 10.985V55.88h15.284V64h8.597l8.12-8.12h12.418l16.716-16.716V0H5.7zm51.104 36.3L47.25 45.85H31.967l-8.12 8.12v-8.12H10.952V5.73h45.85V36.3zM47.25 16.716v16.716h-5.73V16.716h5.73zm-15.284 0v16.716h-5.73V16.716h5.73z"/>
</svg>
```

Slightly hacky, especially if you need a background element like a `<rect>`.

#### Centering and scaling by recalculating path coordinates

Most likely, a transform works perfectly fine and should be your first choice.
If you need your transformations to be "hard coded" – it's not too complicated:

```js
let svg = document.querySelector(".svg");
let path = svg.querySelector("path");
let bBox = svg.getBBox();
let vBox = svg.getAttribute("viewBox");
let vBoxArr = vBox ? vBox.split(" ") : [0, 0, bBox.width, bBox.height];


scalePathProportional(path, 0.75);
centerPath(path, true, true);

function centerPath(path, centerX= true, centerY=true, precision=3, render=true){
  let svg = path.closest('svg');
  let viewBox = svg.getAttribute('viewBox');
  let bBox = svg.getBBox();
  viewBox = viewBox ? viewBox.split(' ') : ([bBox.x, bBox.y, bBox.width, bBox.height]);  
  let offXnorm = viewBox[0] * (-1);
  let offYnorm = viewBox[1] * (-1);
  
  // convert to relative to move only M
  let dRel = snapPathToRelative(path, 1);
  let pathBB = path.getBBox();
  let pX = pathBB["x"];
  let pY = pathBB["y"];
  // get x/y offsets to center path
  let shiftX = (viewBox[2] - pathBB.width) / 2  - pX ;
  let shiftY = (viewBox[3] - pathBB.height) / 2 - pY;
  // save them to pathData
  dRel[0][1] = (dRel[0][1] + shiftX).toFixed(precision) * 1;
  dRel[0][2] = (dRel[0][2] + shiftY).toFixed(precision) * 1;
  // apply change
  if(render){
      path.setAttribute('d',dRel.toString());
  }
  return dRel;
}

//scale to path to width and height by units or percentages
function scalePathProportional(path, scale=1) {
  let svg = path.closest("svg");
  let pathData = path.getPathData();
  pathData.forEach(function (command, p) {
    let coords = command.values;
    //scale coordinates if viewBox < 1000 units
    if (scale!==1) {
      coords.forEach(function (el, i) {
        coords[i] = coords[i] * scale;
      });
    }
  });
  path.setPathData(pathData);
  return pathData;
}


function snapPathToRelative(path, precicion=null, render=false){
  let d = path.getAttribute('d');
  let pathRel = Snap.path.toRelative(d);
  if(precicion){
    roundCoords(pathRel)
  }
  if(render){
      path.setAttribute('d', pathRel.toString());
  }
  return pathRel;
}

function roundCoords(commands, decimals=1){
commands.forEach(function (coordinates, i) {
        let coordRelative = [];
        coordinates.forEach(function (coordinate, v) {
            if (typeof coordinate === 'number') {
                coordinate = (coordinate).toFixed(decimals) * 1
            }
            coordRelative.push(coordinate);
        });
        commands[i] = coordRelative;
    });
    //console.log(commands)
    return commands;
}
```

```css
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 5em;
  font-size: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color:#444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.5.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/path-data-polyfill@1.0.3/path-data-polyfill.min.js"></script>
<svg class="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 72 72">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#444444" />
    <path d="M5.7 0L1.4 10.985V55.88h15.284V64h8.597l8.12-8.12h12.418l16.716-16.716V0H5.7zm51.104 36.3L47.25 45.85H31.967l-8.12 8.12v-8.12H10.952V5.73h45.85V36.3zM47.25 16.716v16.716h-5.73V16.716h5.73zm-15.284 0v16.716h-5.73V16.716h5.73z" fill="#6441A4" />
</svg>
```

**Scaling d coordinates proportionally**
Requires to loop through all path commands and multiply all coordinates by a scaling factor (like 0.75).
To get the path data, I use [Jarek Foksa's pathData polyfill](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill)

**Centering paths**
Involves some comparisons between the parent svg's viewBox and the actual path's  boundaries (retrieved via `path.getBBox()`).
To actually shift the path horizontally and vertically by x/y offsets we can simplify the task by converting the path commands to relative coordinates (using [snap.svg's](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/) `toRelative(d)`.
Now we only need to change the M command's x/y coordinates (see also Lea Verou's post [Convert SVG path to all-relative or all-absolute commands](https://lea.verou.me/2019/05/utility-convert-svg-path-to-all-relative-or-all-absolute-commands/))

**Disclaimer: not intended for live usage **
This approach should be used for custom svg pre-optimizing. So run the script - re-save your svg asset.